# Laravel 5.4: INSERT statement error

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm attempting to insert data:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Venues;

class VenuesManageController extends Controller
{

    public function insert(Request $request)
    {

        Venues::insert('INSERT INTO venues (
                            id,
                            fields,
                            created_at,
                            updated_at
                        )
                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                            [
                                null,
                                $request->fields,
                                $request->created_at,
                                $request->updated_at
                            ]
                        );

    }

}
```

... but I'm getting an error:

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() must be of the type array,
>   string given, called in
>   /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php
>   on line 1251
>
> in Builder.php (line 2093) at Builder->insert('INSERT INTO venues
>   ( id, name,   bedrooms,   telephone,  fax,    email,  street, towns_cities,
>   counties, post_codes, nation_names,   venues_geo_nation_id,   currencies, website,    status, created_at, updated_at  )
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
>   array(null, 'ACME Inc', '5555', '778899', '77777',
>   'me@somewhere.com', 'Address',
>   'County', 'Town', 'Post Code', '235', 'S720BP', 'United
>   Kingdom', 'EUR', 'somewhere.com', '0', '2017-10-20 14:25:23',
>   '2017-10-20 14:25:23')) in Builder.php (line 1251)

I tried removing the `Request` string, but got another error:

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError Type error: Too few arguments to function
>   App\Http\Controllers\VenuesManageController::insert(), 0 passed and
>   exactly 1 expected

Please note: I've trimmed some of code down, but the basic data sending from web page to controllers is working.

But having followed [the instructions in the Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#running-queries), I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: You're using a model, not the DB class...  Consult the ORM docs, make sure you always select the correct version, you titled 5.4 but linked to 5.0, there are very big differences between 5.4 and 5.0

Comment: Is `$request->fields` a string or an array? If it's an array, then you need to try building your insert query differently. The query in the error looks right to me, but it also does not match the code you posted.

Comment: You can actually make this easier by settings those columns to `fillable` in your model, then if `$request->fields` contains an associative array of columns -> values, then do `Venues::create($request->fields);`

Comment: @Devon, if you look at the syntax for INSERT statement, there's no difference between 5 and 5.4

Comment: @WayneSmallman and you disrgearded my first statement.  That DOC is for the DB class, not the Eloquent Model.

Comment: @Devon, it would be a big help if you gave me a code example; I've been at this for about 5 hours and flailing on StackOverflow is the high water mark.

Comment: You're calling `Venues::insert` not `DB::insert`....  This is pretty basic stuff, I suggest you go back and read through the entire Laravel docs and familiarize yourself with the difference between a model and the DB class.  DB class is for generic database operations, model classes deal with operations specifically around one object/table.  Model::insert is not the same as DB::insert

Comment: Looking through the code, Devon is correct. The Eloquent insert only calls for an array of values, not the query string + array of values that the `DB` insert function requires. The code can be found within `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php`

Comment: I think the main point that's becoming lost here is that instead of something simple, we're talking about ORM, Eloquent, and Illuminate etc instead of the one single thing. As I said, I've been at this for hours — reading the documentation — and little of it has made sense, thus me turning up here. That aside, thank you for the assistance!

Comment: Yeah, Laravel won't be simple to understand if you don't understand PHP and Object Oriented Programming.  There's a reason why most companies want someone with 5 years of experience to work on their site, just keep that in mind when spending "hours" trying to understand something, that most of us have spent years to truly understand it.